# how do i access the value of selectedCurrency

Tags: javascript

there is a value in selectedCurrency that keeps changing I want to access it so I tried the following code below the problem is it is giving me an error "cannot read property price of undefined" so I guess instead of using the value of selectedCurrency its using selectedCurrency as an object.
How do I write this properly?

```
data.priceDetails.selectedCurrency.price
```

Comment: You should start by knowing the language you're using. Based on the error, it's JavaScript, not Java. Java is to JavaScript what a Car is to a Carpet.

Comment: The message clearly says that `data.priceDetails.selectedCurrency` is undefined. Accessing a property (`price`) of undefined doesn't make sense.